# About the k-th derivative of the Delta function

Tags: measure-theory, distribution-theory

I need some help to compute the k-th derivative of the Dirac's Delta function, $\delta_0^{(k)}$.

I know its Fourier transform is $TF(\delta_0^{(k)})(y)=(iy)^{k}$( I don't know if this could be useful).

Thanks a lot for any help.

---

EDIT. Context of the question:

I'm trying to obtain the fourier transform of $y^k$. To do that, I am trying to use the next expression, that I have proved: $TF(\delta_{0}^{(k)})(y)=(iy)^k$.

Then, if I apply Fourier transform to the previous expression, I have:

$\delta_0^{(k)}(-y)=TF(\small{TF(\delta_{0}^{(k)})})(y)=i^k\;TF(y^k)$

and this implies $\delta_0^{(k)}(y)=i^k\;TF((-y)^k)$, which leads to $TF(y^k)=\frac{1}{(-1)^ki^k}\overbrace{\delta_0^{(k)}(y)}^{*}$,

And that's why I need to obtain an expression for *.

Comment: I do not see your problem, really. From the very definition, for any $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$, we have $\delta_0^{(k)}(\phi) = (-1)^k\delta_0(\phi^{(k)}) = (-1)^k\phi^{(k)}(0)$. Can you point to your problem?

Comment: I have edited the post with the context of the question. From what you say, can we deduce the following? $$TF(y^k)(\phi)=\frac{1}{(-1)^ky^k}(-1)^k\phi^{(k)}(0)$$?


I think the fact that $TF(\delta_0^{(k)})$ gave as a result a funtion, made me think that $TF(y^k)$ should be a function too, but I see it's not the case, isn't it?

Comment: So $$F(y^k)(\phi) = y^k(F(\phi)) = i^{-k} F(\delta^{(k)}_0)F(\phi) = i^{-k} \delta^{(k)}_0(\phi(-x)) = i^{k} \phi^{(k)}(0)$$

Answer (score 3):

The comment contains the correct answer.  Distributions are only defined in terms of how they act when integrated against test functions.  So with an abuse of notation:
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} \phi(x) \delta(x) \, dx = \phi(0) ,$$
and by integrating by parts $k$ times
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} \phi(x) \delta^{(k)}(x) \, dx = (-1)^{k-1} \phi^{(k)}(0) .$$

You can also see this intuitively by approximating the $\delta$ function by $n \psi(n x)$, where $\psi(x)$ is smooth, non-negative, supported in a neighbourhood of $0$, and $\int_{\mathbb R} \psi(x) \, dx = 1$, and then letting $n$ be very large.  Think about what the derivatives of this might look like, and you will see why the second displayed equation is intuitively reasonable.